# Ошибка при создании триггера на точную дату и время GAS

Tags: google-apps-script

Я не понимаю что от меня хочет гугл скрипт, раньше все работало, а сейчас когда я хочу создать триггер у меня почему то подсвечивается дата и время как будто они в неверном формате, но я по образцу пишу, пробовал и раскладку менять и с запятой и без запятой, не понимаю что происходит[image: Скриншот создание триггера]

Comment: Ошибка известная, но надо писать фидбэк по интерфейсу непосредственно из приложения Apps Script. Вверху справа под иконкой вопроса в кружке. К сожалению, никак не наберет критической массы, чтобы это можно было исправить =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашел видео про этот триггер и там формат другой, попробовал, работает, без комментариев...
[image: Боже]